# Pinch zoom not working [ANDROID]

Tags: android, imageview, zooming, pinchzoom

I am creating an app where I am implementing various zoom functionalities on same `ImageView`. I have written code for pinch zoom, it doesn't show any error or exception but its not working. I have used `GestureDetector` for double tap and swipe functionality and using `ScaleGestureDetector` for **pinch zoom**
Here is my code is there something wrong with it?

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView iv;
private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
private Matrix original_matrix = new Matrix();
private float x1,x2;
static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 150;
private Matrix matrix_scale=new Matrix();
int view_height;
int view_width;
int drawable_height;
int drawable_width;
Drawable drawable;
Bitmap bmp;
private float scale = 1f;
private ScaleGestureDetector SGD;
private  Matrix matrix_pinch=new Matrix();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_demo_gestures);
    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getResources(), R.drawable.demoimg), size.x, size.y, true);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    view_height=iv.getHeight();
    view_width=iv.getWidth();
    drawable=iv.getDrawable();
    drawable_height=drawable.getMinimumHeight();
    drawable_width=drawable.getMinimumWidth();
    SGD = new ScaleGestureDetector(this,new ScaleListener());
    iv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(SecondActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            int check_zoom_state = 0;
            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                switch (check_zoom_state) {
                    case 0:
                        float scalefactor = Math.max(1.1f, Math.min(3.0f, 4.0f));
                        float x = e.getX();
                        float y = e.getY();
                        matrix.setScale(scalefactor, scalefactor, x, y);
                        iv.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                        check_zoom_state = 1;
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        //iv.setImageMatrix(original_matrix);
                       // iv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                        iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.demoimg);
                        float scale_X = view_width / drawable_width;
                        float scale_Y = view_height / drawable_height;
                        original_matrix.setScale(scale_X, scale_Y);
                        iv.setImageMatrix(original_matrix);
                        check_zoom_state = 0;
                        break;
                    default:
                        float scalefactor1 = Math.max(1.1f, Math.min(3.0f, 4.0f));
                        float x1 = e.getX();
                        float y1 = e.getY();
                        matrix.setScale(scalefactor1, scalefactor1, x1, y1);
                        iv.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                        check_zoom_state = 1;

                }
                   return super.onDoubleTap(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {
               //iv.setImageMatrix(original_matrix);
            /*    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Long Pressed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
                //iv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.demoimg);
                float scale_X = view_width / drawable_width;
                float scale_Y = view_height / drawable_height;
                original_matrix.setScale(scale_X, scale_Y);
                iv.setImageMatrix(original_matrix);
            }

        });

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    x1 = event.getX();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    x2 = event.getX();
                    float deltaX = x2 - x1;

                    if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE)
                    {
                        // Left to Right swipe action
                        if (x2 > x1)
                        {
                           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Left to Right swipe [Next]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }

                        // Right to left swipe action
                        /*else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Right to Left swipe [Previous]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }*/

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // consider as something else - a screen tap for example
                    }
                    break;
            }
            gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);

    return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    SGD.onTouchEvent(ev);
    return true;
}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.

        SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        scale *= detector.getScaleFactor();
        scale = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scale, 5.0f));

        matrix_pinch.setScale(scale, scale);
        iv.setImageMatrix(matrix_pinch);
        return true;
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example - [Multitouch Image](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/multi-touch-panning-pinch-zoom-image-view-in-android-using/)

Declare Global inside Activity

```
    //variable for counting two successive up-down events
int clickCount = 0;
//variable for storing the time of first click
long startTime;
//variable for calculating the total time
long duration;
//constant for defining the time duration between the click that can be considered as double-tap
static final int MAX_DURATION = 500;
```

For Double Tap listening you can use this code inside `OnTouch`

```
  switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            clickCount++;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            duration=  duration + time;
            if(clickCount == 2)
            {
                if(duration<= MAX_DURATION)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "double tap", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                clickCount = 0;
                duration = 0;
                break;
            }
    }
```

Comment: ypp that is working for pinch zoom but i have to do this along with double tap functionality

Comment: my repuation score is less than 15 thats why vote is not diplayed yet

Comment: my reputation score is less than 15 thats why vote is not diplayed yet..and accepted (through green tick)

Comment: hey here if want to make a sequence that on first time double tap image zooms in then on second time double pat it zooms out then on 3rd time it zooms in. how it will be achieved?

Comment: if ((double_tap_count % 2) != 0){
                                    perform zoom out
                                }

Comment: else{perform zoom in} double_tap_count++

Comment: i did this but it works for one time only i mean it zooms in on first double tap then zooms out on second double tap then zooms in on third double tap then never zooms out

Comment: Simple way to achieve this is create one Boolean flag called IsZoomEnabled =false default.... and on double tap check if IsZoomEnabled is enabled or not... and call appropriate task in if else

Comment: if this does not work then add one new question with your new  code

Comment: case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            boolean IsZoomEnabled =false;
                                    if (IsZoomEnabled==false){
                                   
                                    float scalefactor = Math.max(1.1f, Math.min(3.0f, 4.0f));
                                    matrix.setScale(scalefactor, scalefactor, x, y);
                                    setImageMatrix(matrix);
                                    IsZoomEnabled=true;
                                }

Comment: else{perform zoom out and then IsZoomEnabled=false;} but that way it nevers goes to else block